# How can one display local time and date to my drupal website visitors depending upon their geographic location?

Tags: date, drupal-6, view

I need to display the FIFA world Cup 2010 schedule on my Drupal website. But what I want is that each visitor should be able to see the time for the upcoming matching as per his/her own geographic location . How can this be done ?Any suggestions would be welcomed. Thanks for reading this through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be able to sniff the user's location. The most common way of doing that is by using an IP-to-location [service](http://fireeagle.yahoo.net/developer) or [library](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity). There are [freely available](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity) IP-to-location libraries which provide country-level resolution, or you can pay to get data that is accurate down to city level.

There is a contrib module which allows you to incorporate the MaxMind GeoIP more easily. http://drupal.org/project/geoip

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a tool like GeoIP,  i don't know Drupal so this is just a hint... just a thought!

Answer (score 0):

You can put a time zone spinner with the World Cup schedule on your website, and let your users convert the match times to their local time if they select their local time zone from the spinner.

Answer (score 0):

What about JS getTime()?  Wouldn't that work in browser and pull from the user's settings on locale?